# How to capture content within using block while View is rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.0, with the ASPX View Engine.

I currently have a method that uses a regex to match certain words within text and highlights them accordingly. So far I am using this to process large amounts of text that are being read from flat files. The end goal I am trying to achieve in this post is to be able to capture content sections of a View, and process them using the same method.

Here is a basic example of how I'm currently trying to achieve this:

```
<h2>This is a Test</h2>

<p>Line before capture</p>

<% using (Html.CaptureContent())
   { %>

<p>this line should be in capitals</p>

 <%} %>
<p>Line after capture</p>
```

Html.CaptureContent:

```
public static ContentCapture CaptureContent(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    return new ContentCapture(html.ViewContext.HttpContext);
}
```

ContentCapture:

```
public class ContentCapture : IDisposable
{
    private HttpContextBase Context { get; set; }
    private TextWriter OriginalOutput { get; set; }
    private StringWriter CaptureOutput { get; set; }

    public ContentCapture(HttpContextBase context)
    {

        CaptureOutput = new StringWriter();

        //save the default writer in private property
        OriginalOutput = context.Response.Output;
        Context = context;

        Context.Response.Output = CaptureOutput;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        string processedContent = CaptureOutput.ToString().ToUpper();

        Context.Response.Output = OriginalOutput;
        Context.Response.Output.Write(processedContent);
    }
}
```

When I run this the output is exactly as the tags are in the View, with no processing applied to the <p> tag within the using block. I have tried a couple of variations but with no success. I'm guessing I've made an incorrect assumption of how the View would be rendered as putting a breakpoint in the dispose method has shown me that nothing has been written to the StringWriter object.

Does anyone know of a way I can achieve the desired affect? I'd prefer not to resort to having all the content sections in hard-coded strings being returned by a helper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to the ViewContext like this:

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("some content");
```

So you will have to do some refactoring to use that instead of the HttpContext that you are currently passing through.